# Getting " when trying to replace a character in string

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I want to replace `"` from a string with `^`.

```
String str = "hello \"there";
System.out.println(str);
String str1 = str.replaceAll("\"", "^");
System.out.println(str1);
String str2= str1.replaceAll("^", "\"");
System.out.println(str2);
```

and the output is :

```
hello "there
hello ^there
"hello ^there
```

why I am getting extra `"` in start of string and `^` in between string

I am expecting:

```
hello "there
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method consume a regex for the 1st argument.

the `^` in `String str2= str1.replaceAll("^", "\"");` will match the starting position within the string.
So if you want the `^` char, write `\^`

Hope this code can help:

```
String str2= str1.replaceAll("\\^", "\"");
```

Comment: Then how can i print the output i want

Comment: Yes: use replace instead of replaceAll

Comment: @MauricePerry
`String str2= str1.replaceAll("\\^", "\"");` should works you will "escape" ^ but `\` need to be also escaped :D

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx so would `String str2 = str1.replace("^", "\"");` and it's simpler

Comment: For this case will work also replace instead replace all, but ofc if you will want really to replace all in string, I mean if there will be more occurrence, then you can use it.. As obviously method name says.

Comment: @KumarHarsh updated my answer. hope that can help your question.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `replace` which doesnt use regex

```
String str2 = str1.replace("^", "\"");
```

Comment: or, similar char based `replace('^','"')` Both have better performance than regex versions

Answer (score 3):

`^` means start of a line in regex, you can add two `\` before it:

```
 String str2= str1.replaceAll("\\^", "\"");
```

The first is used to escape for compiling, the second is used to escape for regex.

Answer (score 2):

Since [String::replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) consumes regular expression you need to convert your search and replacement strings into regular expressions first:

```
str.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("\""), Matcher.quoteReplacement("^"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use replaceAll. Is there any specific reason ? 
If you can use replace function then try below
`String str2= str1.replace("^", "\"");`